# Can't access items() of a dictionary returned by a property

Tags: python, django, dictionary

I can't access items() of a dictionary returned by a property i.e.

```
{{obj.prop}}
```

returns dictionary, whereas

```
{{obj.prop.items}}
```

is empty.
Here is the property itself

```
@property
def prop(self):
    return self.__mydict
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: Dunno. Maybe you should show the code of the property.

Comment: Just because the dictionary exists doesn't mean it contains anything.  Are you sure the dictionary has contents?

Comment: {{obj.prop}} displays the content of the dictionary

Comment: I tried to create a dictionary in my views.py and everything work excelently, but it doesn't work with my property

Comment: It is just a dictionary of obj class which I import in models.py

Comment: Do you mean {{obj.prop.items()}} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionary does not have a field called `items`, it has a function called `items` though.

Here's the example from PEP 3106: http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3106/

```
a = d.items()
for k, v in a: ...
# And later, again:
for k, v in a: ...
```

If you want to confirm that, you may go to Python's interactive terminal, create an object (e.g. obj), and type `help(obj.prop)`, you should see all the available fields and functions.

**Back to your question, you should use `obj.prop.items()` instead.**